# How to make Inputbox appear above the keyboard in IOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to create a simple and standard chat window just like WhatsApp, Telegram, etc. Where when the inputbox on the bottom of the screen got focus, the keyboard appear and the inputbox goes right about the keyboard like this...

[image]

This is my code...

```
import React from 'react'
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux'
import {ScrollView, View, TextInput, Text} from 'react-native'

import style from './style'

class Chat extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        Actions.refresh({title: 'Chat'})
    }

    render() {
       return (
           <View  style={{flex:1}}>
              <ScrollView>
                  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                      <Text>Hello !</Text>
                  </View>
              </ScrollView>
              <View style={{borderWidth: 1, padding:15}}>
                  <TextInput/>
              </View>
           </View>
       )
    }
}

export default Chat
```

The result is this very simple one:

[image]

But when my inputbox got focus, the inputbox still got stucked in the bottom of the screen, behind the keyboard. Any suggestion for this ?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure of how to achieve this. But you will probably need [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html)

Comment: You can implement it easily by setting stylesheet. maybe height property of parent view or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to change your input's position when keyboard shows and hides. 
You need to add two listeners for when keyboard shows and hides:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        keyboardHeight: 0,
        inputHeight: 40
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this));
}

_keyboardDidShow(e) {
    this.setState({keyboardHeight: e.endCoordinates.height});
}

_keyboardDidHide(e) { 
     this.setState({keyboardHeight: 0});
}

render() {
    return (
        <TextInput style={{marginBottom: keyboardHeight + inputHeight}} />
    )
}
```

You can also add some animation to make it move smoothly.

Comment: Yes...I used this method...really works ! As you said...Need some animation.

Comment: recommend to change `keyboardDidShow` and `keyboardDidHide` to `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide`

Answer (score 0):

Another Suggestion would be :

[React-Native-Keyboard-Aware-Scroll-View](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

This is great when you have multiples text inputs and does handle some animation. Not perfect but did the job for me.